# Splitting a column in a data frame by an nth instance of a character

Tags: r, dataframe, split, dplyr, character

I have a dataframe with several columns, and one of those columns is populated by pipes "|" and information that I am trying to obtain.

For example:

```
View(Table$Column)
"|1||KK|12|Gold||4K|"
"|1||Rst|E|Silver||13||"
"|1||RST|E|Silver||18||"
"|1||KK|Y|Iron|y|12||"
"|1||||Copper|Cpr|||E"
"|1||||Iron|||12|F"
```

And so on for about 120K rows.
What I am trying to excavate is everything in between the 5th pipe and the 6th pipe in this series, but in it's own column vector, so the end result looks like this:

```
View(Extracted)
Gold
Silver
Silver
Iron
Copper
Iron
```

I don't want to use RegEx. My tools are only limited to R here. Would you guys happen to have any advice how to overcome this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** Assuming x as defined reproducibly in the Note at the end use `read.table` as shown. No regular expressions or packages are used.

```
read.table(text = Table$Column, sep = "|", header = FALSE, 
  as.is = TRUE, fill = TRUE)[6]
```

giving:

```
      V6
1   Gold
2 Silver
3 Silver
4   Iron
5 Copper
6   Iron
```

**2)** This alternative does use a regular expression (which the question asked not to) but just in case here is a tidyr solution.  Note that it requires tidyr 0.8.2 or later since earlier versions of tidyr did not support `NA` in the `into=` argument.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

Table %>% 
  separate(Column, into = c(rep(NA, 5), "commodity"), sep = "\\|", extra = "drop")
```

giving:

```
  commodity
1      Gold
2    Silver
3    Silver
4      Iron
5    Copper
6      Iron
```

**3)** This is another base solution.  It is probably not the one you want given that (1) is so much simpler but I wanted to see if we could come up with a second approach in base that did not use regexes.  Note that if the `split=` argument of `strsplit` is `""` then it is treated specially and so is not a regex.  It creates a list each of whose components is a vector of single characters.  Each such vector is passed to the anonymous function which labels `|` and the characters in the field after it with its ordinal number.  We then take the characters corresponding to 5 (except the first as it is `|`) and collapse them together using `paste`.

```
data.frame(commodities = sapply(strsplit(Table$Column, ""), function(chars) {
  wx <- which(cumsum(chars == "|") == 5)
  paste(chars[seq(wx[2], tail(wx, 1))], collapse = "")
}), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

giving:

```
  commodities
1        Gold
2      Silver
3      Silver
4        Iron
5      Copper
6        Iron
```

### Note

```
Table <- data.frame(Column = c("|1||KK|12|Gold||4K|",
  "|1||Rst|E|Silver||13||",
  "|1||RST|E|Silver||18||",
  "|1||KK|Y|Iron|y|12||",
  "|1||||Copper|Cpr|||E",
  "|1||||Iron|||12|F"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("|1||KK|12|Gold||4K|", "|1||Rst|E|Silver||13||"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
library(stringr)
stringr::str_split(df$x, "\\|", simplify = TRUE)[, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

**1)** We can use `strsplit` from `base R` on the delimiter `|` and extract the 6th element from the `list` of `vector`s

```
sapply(strsplit(Table$Column, "|", fixed = TRUE), `[`, 6)
#[1] "Gold"   "Silver" "Silver" "Iron"   "Copper" "Iron"
```

---

**2)** Or using `regex` (again from `base R`), use `sub` to extract the 6th word

```
sub("^([|][^|]+){4}[|]([^|]*).*", "\\2", 
       gsub("(?<=[|])(?=[|])", "and", Table$Column, perl = TRUE))
#[1] "Gold"   "Silver" "Silver" "Iron"   "Copper" "Iron"
```

#### data

```
Table <- structure(list(Column = c("|1||KK|12|Gold||4K|", 
 "|1||Rst|E|Silver||13||", 
 "|1||RST|E|Silver||18||", "|1||KK|Y|Iron|y|12||", "|1||||Copper|Cpr|||E", 
 "|1||||Iron|||12|F")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -6L))
```